# Question about the meaning of $F(\cdot , t)$

Tags: notation

Context: I'm am doing a problem that wants me to prove you can interchange integrals and derivatives using the Lebesgue DCT. The conditions for the proof say "Assume $F(\cdot , t)$ is Lebesgue measurable", among other things.

What in the heck does that dot mean? It doesn't show it anywhere in the book.

Comment: It's a wildcard. The dot $\cdot$ is _any_ variable you like.

Answer (score 2):

This is the function $s\mapsto F(s,t)$.